# What are the limits of using the suffix "-esque"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, suffixes, morphological-domains

I'm seeing this suffix everywhere lately. Of course, there are a number of *-esques* that are commonly used (i.e. *Kafkaesque*), but is there some sort of rule for determining who (or what) gets assigned which suffix? For instance, was *Orwellian* chosen simply because someone decided it sounded better than "Orwellesque"? What about "Kafkanian"? It all seems very willy-nilly.

Comment: Yea.  It sounded better.  Honestly.

Comment: And different languages chose different suffixes: 'Kafkaesque' in French is 'kafkaïen' (-ian suffix), whereas 'titanic' is 'titanesque', and 'Machiavellian' is 'machiavélique' (-ic suffix).

Comment: [Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Kafkan%2CKafkian%2CKafkaian%2CKafkaesque&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CKafkan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CKafkian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CKafkaian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CKafkaesque%3B%2Cc0) suggests *Kafkaesque* is most common (no surprise). Then *Kafkan*, then *Kafkian*, then *Kafkaian*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I could infer based on the Wikitionary entries, -esque is more likely to be appended to proper nouns than -ian.

> **-esque:** In the style or manner of, resembling; appended to nouns, especially proper nouns, and forming adjectives.
>
> From French -esque ("-ish"), from Italian -esco ("-like"), from Medieval Latin -iscus.
>
> **-ian:** from, related to, or like.
>
> From Latin -ianus.

Also there appear to be nuances in meaning though they seem to have been dulled by conflicting contemporary usage. **-ian** can be used to mean "related to" in addition to "like", e.g. *Machiavellian* could relate to the principles of government as expounded by Machiavelli or something befitting Machiavelli .

**-esque** is generally used only in the sense of being like something or befitting something, e.g. *"Machiavellesque"* could describe something befitting Machiavelli, not necessarily related to his principles (although I am inclined to leave this point open for discussion).

Based on these arguments, I conclude that **-ian** can be used in a much broader context than **-esque** even when both are appended to proper nouns.