# Suffix '-ine' vs. suffix '-like'

Tags: animals

In previous questions we learnt how to use words like 'asinine', 'bovine', 'canine' and 'feline', so, after some deep thoughts,  a question arose in my  mind: why does English, in some cases, not use the suffix *-ine* when describing an animal trait or characteristic present or recognizable in the human beings?

For example, after some searches I observed that you cannot say 'bulline' but you must say 'bulllike', you cannot say 'birdine', but you must say 'birdlike', and so on.

Can anyone explain, also in reference to 'bull', why in some cases you prefer '-ine' and in others you use '-like'?

Comment: Use '-ine' with Latinate roots. Use '-like' with Saxon roots.

Comment: [List of Adjectives that go with particular animals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_names).

Answer (score 2):

As @Mitch indicates in the comment, the basic answer is that *-ine occurs with the Latinate  terms and *-like with the Saxon ones.

Part of the reason is that *genitive* declension of these words in Latin has this basic ending.

English word / Latin nominative / Latin genitive / English adjective

Cow / *bos* / *bovis* / bovine

Cat / *feles* / *felis* / feline

Dog / *canis* / *canis* / canine

Snake / *serpens* / *serepentis* / serpentine

There may be ones where we simulate the same *-ine without a Latin origin, but I cannot think of any off the top of my head.

Comment: *Riverine* and *Wilhelmine* are the only ones I can think of; *-ine* seems to be non-productive. But we still have [-esque and -ian](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16160/what-are-the-limits-of-using-the-suffix-esque) to fall back on.

Comment: @choster but also equine from *equis*

Comment: I'm pretty sure *equus* is Latin.

Comment: Nickel / nickeline are recent, though they are both nouns. I won't mention plasticine.