# "Kafkaesque" vs. "Kafkan"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

Is there any difference in meaning between the adjectives *Kafkaesque* and *Kafkan*, or are they synonyms?

Comment: Not really but it's always Kafkaesque.

Comment: A Kafkan is a long dress-like shirt.

Comment: @Mitch: That's a [kaftan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaftan).

Comment: Related: [Guidelines for selecting suffix when making an adjective out of a proper name: *-esque, -ean, -ian*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150067)

Answer (score 4):

**Kaf·ka·esque**  adj.

1. Of or relating to Franz Kafka or his writings.
2. Marked by surreal distortion and often a sense of impending danger: "Kafkaesque fantasies of the impassive interrogation, the false trial, the confiscated passport . . . haunt his innocence" (New Yorker).

The adjective [**kafkan**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Kafkan,%20kafkaesque&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,Kafkan;,c0;.t1;,kafkaesque;,c0), though used, is not easily found in dictionaries.

I think that *kafkan* is more used in the meaning n. 2 of the above definitions.

Comment: Thanx for your response. Tho word Kafkan is used for example in Milan Kundera´s The Art of The Novel for the description of Kafka´s singular poetic quality. I ´m not sure but I think that Kafkaesque has rather negative connotation, for example critical parasatism and exploitation of Kafka´s work.

Comment: You have raised an interesting issue, more research needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

The first Google Books search result for either *Kafkan* or *Kafkaesque* involves an author struggling with this very question of how to make a suitable adjective form of *Kafka*. From [*The New Yorker*](https://books.google.com/books?id=U5ciAQAAMAAJ&q=%22recommended+with+some+warmth+looking%22&dq=%22recommended+with+some+warmth+looking%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMInKPlueSYxwIVWC6ICh1E5Ap4), volume 14 (1938) [combined snippets]:

> ...very Franz Kafka-ish (Kafkan? What is the adjective?), called "The Wild Goose Chase," which I seem to have recommended with some warmth. Looking back on it now, I feel that it was more confused than original, my primary reaction having been vice versa. Of those whom my ill-considered praise may have led to a bewildered stab at Mr. Warner's cryptic allegory, I crave pardon.

The earliest Google Books Match for *Kafkaesque* is from eleven years later, [in 1949](https://books.google.com/books?id=ft_VAAAAMAAJ&q=%22kafkaesque%22&dq=%22kafkaesque%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAThQahUKEwjr5cn-5ZjHAhUFl4gKHWsICx4).

Google Books actually finds a sufficient number of matches to track Kafkaesque (red line), Kafkan (blue line), and Kafkaish (green line), thought he green line looks pretty flat in this Ngram chart for the years 1935–2005:

[image]

Today the clearly preferred form is *Kafkaesque*, a point underscored by the fact that *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) has an entry for *Kafkaesque* (which it dates to 1946) but no mention *Kafkan* or *Kafkaish* as variants. Incidentally, the *Eleventh Collegiate* has only one definition for Kafkaesque, unlike the dictionary that Josh61 cites in his answer:

> **Kafkaesque** *adj* (1946) : of, relating to, or suggestive of Franz Kafka or his writings; esp : having a nightmarishly complex, bizarre, or illogical quality.

In my opinion all three of the words discussed here are recognizable adjective forms of *Kafka*, but I don't think that they have substantively different meanings, and I don't see any reason in general to stray from using the most familiar form, *Kafkaesque*.

Answer (score 0):

Kafkan: (a person or character) of a type epitomised by Kafka or one of his characters.

kafkaesque: (a situation, problem, or plot) recalling the nightmarish situations described in Kafka's stories.

Comment: Please cite sources.

Comment: Or, if these are not quotes, please add supporting material.