# Is there a rule for transforming surnames into adjectives?

Tags: suffixes

To be sure, there's a whole bunch of suffixes that are used for this, and some transformations seem to be completely arbitrary while some others deliberate and even a bit contrite.

**Rubenesque** actually takes liberties with the painter's name, which is Rubens, as does

**Thoreauvian**, from Thoreau.

**Platonic** takes advantage of the original Greek spelling of Plato's name (Platon). Shouldn't it be *Platoesque* instead?

**Byronic** is straight-forward enough. What about

**Shavian**, though? When did G.B. Shaw ever ask for a good shave?

And what are you supposed to do with

*Edgar Allan Poe*
*Giacomo Puccini*
or even *Leonardo*, for that matter?

There are no duplicates of this question. One seeming duplicate only touches upon the subject lightly and approaches the matter from a different angle.

Comment: *Puccinian* and *Leonadine* is used sometimes. There are *Marxist* and *Trotskyite*.

Comment: Also: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150067/guidelines-for-selecting-suffix-when-making-an-adjective-out-of-a-proper-name

Comment: @Henry: Uh ... Marxist, like Pucciniist, means something else. As do Wagnerian, Wagnerist, and Wagnerite.

Comment: ***List of eponymous adjectives in English*** - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_eponymous_adjectives_in_English - ***Eponym*** - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eponym

Comment: @Josh: I thought I was asking for a list of rules rather than examples.

Comment: As for ***Platonic (adj.)*** - 
1530s, "of or pertaining to Greek philosopher Plato" (429 B.C.E.-c. 347 B.C.E.), ***from Latin Platonicus, from Greek Platonikos.*** The meaning "free of sensual desire" (1630s), which the word usually carries nowadays, is a Renaissance notion. ***Platonesque***   - Suggestive or characteristic of Plato or his ideas.https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/platonesque

Comment: Your question is too broad. Eponyms formation depends on a lot of factors, etymology, usage, meaning...etc. You might concentrate on a few specific instances. In the second Wikipedia kink there are a few indications on eponyms usage...you should show your own research first.

Comment: ***Puccinian*** - Of or belonging to Puccini; relating to or characteristic of his operas; specifically melodic, richly orchestral, lyrical; excessively operatic; conventionally dramatic or sentimental.
Related ***Pucciniesque*** - https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/puccinian

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150067/guidelines-for-selecting-suffix-when-making-an-adjective-out-of-a-proper-name

Comment: @josh: I'm not looking for anything in particular. I guess I'm just trying to remind folks that this here forum is titled English Language & Usage, and not, say, ELL ... or ESL, for that matter.

Comment: @Ricky - as a 10k plus user, you are supposed to know how to ask an on-topic question.