# Suffix for an adherent with person's name as root

Tags: suffixes, demonyms

We can refer to a particular method devised by Newton as the "Newtonian method" or a distribution attributed to Laplace might be referred to as the "Laplacian Distribution".

Some colleagues were having a [lively discussion](https://twitter.com/EJWagenmakers/status/1177167759844790272) on what would be the analog for the name "Jeffreys" (note the 's'). Some suggestions:

1. Jeffreysian
2. Jeffreyian
3. Jeffreyic
4. Jeffreysic
5. Jeffrecian

My vote is for "Jeffrecian" mostly because of the similarity of the last sound in Jeffreys to Belize, for which the demonym is Belizean. Thoughts? Note: I'm aware there is definitely not a right answer and this is mostly for fun :)

Related question I just found: [Guidelines for selecting suffix when making an adjective out of a proper name (-esque, -ean, -ian,](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150067/guidelines-for-selecting-suffix-when-making-an-adjective-out-of-a-proper-name?rq=1)

Comment: I suggest Jeffrish. `:P`

Comment: I would use -ite or -ette.

Comment: I have to disagree with the original question. While I agree that it's fun, I don't agree that there's not a right answer ;)

Comment: For other kinds of adherent, there are also *–ite* and *–ist*.

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously Jeffreysian. Think Keynesian economics.

Comment: And Bayesian inference in statistics.

Comment: Of course! I'm slapping myself on the forehead right now for not thinking of that as my example, but I've been thinking a lot about economic stuff lately so go figure huh?

Comment: And (however ugly it sounds) JeffREEZian, on analogy with BeethoVEENian, WagNEERian, ABEELian, NoethEERian etc. And I've just remembered Rafflesia.

Comment: What's wrong with "Jeffreysonian"?

Comment: @Hot Licks I'm not sure actually. I just think that "-ian" is the standard eponymous suffix for names ending in an "s". I can think of another reason, though: "Jeffreysonian" is longer than "Jeffreysian", syllable-wise, so the natural choice is the latter.