# "Science fiction-y"

Tags: adjectives, suffixes

I recently saw a TED Talk in which the speaker used the term "science fiction-y", making an adjective out of "science fiction". Is it ok to form your own adjectives in that way? If so, should there be a hyphen before the y (as there was in the captions). Are there other examples of similar constructs with a '-y' added to a term (rather than a single word)? Would science fiction-like be a better choice?

Comment: Since they were armed in 2016, the English Language Police have had orders to use deadly force to prevent this sort of thing.

Comment: Using it will get you respect among the people interested in the topic at your pub, but will fail to impress a teacher or tutor. It's also imprecise; does the -y suffix mean 'something quite like [science fiction]', as opposed to 'belonging to the genre'? / The -like suffix is usually far more acceptable in formal contexts, but even here, some caution should be exercised. Whippersnapper-like? Sonologist-like? // Why doesn't the usual attributive noun usage (as in _science fiction writer_) work in your example ?

Comment: @Rob_Ster I guess that's supposed to be funny and I guess I asked for it by asking if it was "ok". I didn't mean it like that though. The speaker (like me) was not a native English speaker and I wanted to know if this was a generally accepted or common thing to do and if there were other examples.

Comment: @Manne2000 - You've got a good answer below.  For what it's worth, coining a ***nonce word*** can be risky for one with an inexperienced ear for English.  Get it just right, and you're a brilliant conversationalist.  Get it wrong and you burn.

Answer (score 5):

There are at once no examples of similar constructs and an infinite number of them. The speaker was not so much coining a new term as employing a **[nonce word](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110810105507870)**, a word invented to serve an immediate communications need.

Literary nonsense words are a commonly taught category: *vorpal*, *runcible*, *cromulent*. More prosaically, however, it is common to use nonce words in the absence of a more-established or better-known word or phrase. As there is no common term for *sharing characteristics of science fiction*, the speaker has added the adjective-producing suffix *-y* (e.g. *sunny*, *fluffy*, *tricky*) to produce one that the audience will understand even if it is not in common usage. The intent is not to establish new terminology, but merely to move the conversation along.

Essentially every word in the language can be modified in this way, especially in casual communication, but only rarely do these words become fully lexicalized and make their way into dictionaries or other references.

The broader linguistic concept of the use of a grammatical process or pattern with new words and phrases is *[productivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_%28linguistics%29)*. The suffix *-y* is a *productive* suffix because a native speaker will generally understand its use to create an adjective (or noun or diminutive, in other cases) from a word, even if unfamiliar with the word. The speaker could alternatively have said *science fiction-ish*, for example; *-ish* is another productive adjectival suffix indicating something with qualities like or associated with the root.

A web search will turn up various lists of productive, semi-productive, and non-productive prefixes and suffixes in English, but which suffix you choose for a particular word depends on factors ranging from ease of pronunciation to similarity with more established words. For instance, the speaker might have considered *science fiction-some* too distracting, as *-some* is less productive than *-y*, even though we have common words like *troublesome* and *tiresome* that originate in it. In other situations, however, it might have been preferred for contrast or irony. Like any word choice, such matters come down to the speaker or author's taste and the specific need the word is supposed to meet, and are well outside the scope of this site. Some past questions on this site include *[Guidelines for selecting suffix when making an adjective out of a proper name (-esque, -ean, -ian,](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150067)* and *[What are the limits of using the suffix "-esque"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16160)*

As for transcription, I would say the hyphen is not strictly necessary for understanding, but it helps communicate that the word is a nonce. Without it, the reader might consider it an error instead of the intended word, as *science fiction-y* is not a term in general usage. Depending on the style in use, quotation marks, italicization, or other mechanical distinctions may also be appropriate.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of productivity, especially. I would only perhaps add that the -y suffix is *very* productive online and in casual speech, though the hyphen makes it hard to find examples. It may also have somewhat different connotations than either -ish or -like or -some, beyond just ease-of-use. In particular, I would think *science fiction-y* means something like "getting close to being science fiction" whereas *science fiction-ish* is more like "not really science fiction (even if it wants to be)". YMMV on the connotations, though.

Comment: Thanks for this great and extensive explanation! Like the commenter above I also find it hard to find examples online but if I try myself with compound nouns, it seems to work for some (Your living room looks bedroom-y, the candy has a toothpaste-y taste) but not for others (He seems policeman-y, Her desk looks dining table-y). Don't know what the criteria might be for when it works and not (and I am not a native speaker so not sure if my feel for it is correct).